# File creation in Eclipse on linux depends on how it Eclipse is started

Tags: eclipse, file, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, creation

I am making my own Eclipse plugin but ran into unexpected behavior.

When running Eclipse from Command Line:

```
$ cd /home/user/downloads;/home/user/eclipse/eclipse
```

And i call functionality which creates a new file outside the workspace:

```java
new java.io.File("home/user/folder/file")
```

it will return a new file with the path:

```
/home/user/downloads/home/user/folder/file
```

So it adds the path of the change directory command when i started eclipse.

If this is intentionally how should i create my file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such class as `java.net.File` presumably you mean `java.io.File`

The path `home/user/folder/file` is a relative path - that is it is relative to the current directory whatever that may be. So if your current directory is `/home/user/downloads` the full file path will be `/home/user/downloads/home/user/folder/file`

If you don't want this to happen you must specify an **absolute** path - on Unix, Linux and Macs that is a path starting with `/` so

```java
new java.io.File("/home/user/folder/file");
```

(note the leading `/`) will give you a file with that exact path.

Comment: java.net.file was indeed a typo and should be java.io.file. The solution crossed my thought but i dismissed it because it did work as an absolute path without starting eclipse from command line.  But i will give it a go anyway thanks

Comment: The value of the current directory can vary a lot depending on how things are run so it is best to avoid relative paths whenever possible.